# How do I move 'home' to the main Ubuntu partition

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, home-directory

I am completely new to Linux and Ubuntu 13. So far, I'm loving it. The writers really tried to think of everything, and have done a good job of keeping the O/S modern. Nonetheless, it is still a bit of a learning curve to me. I have some experience using a terminal from OS X, but I'm still learning my way around and how things are done. So to anyone who answers, please assume I know *nothing*, and explain each step.

During the O/S installation, I chose to place my 'home' on a separate partition. I did this so I could use this space as portable area where I could store frequently accessed files, use it to transfer stuff between O/S's, and be able to retrieve them easily in an emergency. I formatted this partition using XFS, thinking it was an acronym for exFAT File System, an ideal cross-platform FS which supports files larger than 4GB. Doh! Turns out XFS is a somewhat obscure journaled, server FS. Also turns out 'home' likes to live in a FS that supports permissions, so that rules out exFAT anyway. OK so that was a learning experience, but now I want to move 'home' back to the partition which Ubuntu is installed on, and reformat the XFS partition to something else (decide later).

I read a few related questions here on Ask Ubuntu, but I didn't get anywhere. Either because there were some differences in my situation or version, or I got unexpected results, or I simply didn't know what I was doing. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming that there's nothing on the `/home` partition that you need, correct?

Comment: here would be my suggestion to you boot up a live CD backup all files that are in /home
then use Gparted to format /home as Ext2 or Ext3.
there is a driver for Windows that supports read/write of Ext2/3 filesystems
after formatting place the files back and reboot
I can give more detailed instructions if you like?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. 

Alaa: There's nothing on the `/home` partition that *I* need, but I was under the impression that Linux needs that directory. Also, Ubuntu has placed a directory there labelled with my user name, and it contains more directories called documents, pictures etc...

Comment: Okay, if I understand you correctly, you can accomplish what you are trying to do in another way. The "`/home`" folder will be in the Ubuntu partition, but your `/home/userName/Documents` and all those folders will be on another partition. This other partition can be set to FAT or NTFS, so that you can access those folders through Windows for example. However, all of the files under those folders will have a fixed set of permissions and ownership in Linux. These fixed permissions can be changed, but they change the whole partition, not single files.

Comment: Is this feasible for you? Or do you want to proceed with what you are asking in the question, to just bring back `/home` to the Ubuntu partition? The first set of steps for both of these solutions is the same, but I'm asking just for the sake of what to type when answering your question.

Comment: Taylor: Thanks, I think I can handle that. What is the driver called and where can I get it please? I'm not completely sold on this idea yet. From what I've read, using Ext in OS X (ie my laptop) can be problematic . Since support is non-native it can be slow, cumbersome and buggy. I'm trying to keep effort expenditure to a minimum here so I'll only try it if it's simple and easy to use.

Comment: Alaa: Woah. That's a bit confusing. You mean `/home` will be in one partition, and then a subdirectory will be in another? I'm still trying to wrap my head around how Linux organises files. It seems that the hierarchial structure observed while working with it, doesn't truly reflect how files are actually stored on disk. Directories link to various places, and sometimes there is more than one way to get to a file. How does one keep track of what is where in this labyrinth??  Anyway, given the complications with permissions, maybe it would be better to just "bring it back" as you say. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note 1**: The below will assume that you have a USB stick which you used to install Ubuntu, but the same goes for using a CD. So, wherever you see "USB", it's basically "the media at which you made bootable with Ubuntu".
>
> **Note 2**: Wherever you see `userName` in the commands, replace it with your actual username that you use in your Ubuntu.

Okay, what we'll be doing is booting into live Ubuntu using a LiveUSB. So, if you still have the USB you used with Ubuntu on it, then just boot from it, as if you were going to install Ubuntu from scratch, except, we'll choose to **Try Ubuntu**, not install Ubuntu. This will boot up Ubuntu from the USB, so this is *not* your actual installed Ubuntu. <sub>[Too many "Ubuntu's".]</sub>

All of the following will be typed in a terminal. You can open one by  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

> **Note**: If, at any point, you get an error, stop, and let us know.

1. `sudo mkdir /media/rt`

   - This will create a directory called `rt` under `/media`. This will be the folder that will be housing your actual Ubuntu root partition.
2. `sudo mount /dev/sda3 /media/rt`

   - As apparent from the command, this will mount (make accessible) `/dev/sda3` (your root partition) on the folder `/media/rt`.
   - Note: if the command gives you an error about the "file system type", do `sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda3 /media/rt` instead.
3. `cd /media/rt`

   - This will change our working directory to that directory, which is now your Ubuntu's `/` partition.
4. `sudo chroot --userspec=userName:userName .` Don't forget, replace `userName` with your Ubuntu username.

   - This...well...basically, the prompt that you see now would be the same prompt you would get if you opened a terminal in your actual Ubuntu installation. Your prompt should change to `userName@hostname:$`, something like that.
5. `sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak`

   > **Note**: I'm not entirely sure if this command will ask you to enter a password. But if it does, enter your username's password. This goes for all the remaining commands.

   - This is taking a backup of the file `fstab` that we're going to edit in the following couple of steps.
6. `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`

   - This will open up that `fstab` file, of your Ubuntu installation, in a text editor. This file is responsible for mounting the `/home` partition at startup when you boot up your Ubuntu. It's also responsible for mounting the `/` partition, so be careful with editing this file.
7. Look for the following two lines:

   ```
   # /home was on /dev/sda4 during installation
   UUID=<random-numbers> /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
   ```

   They won't be *exactly* the same as this. You'll probably find exactly the first line, but the second line might be slightly different. It could start with `/dev/sda4` instead of `UUID=<random-numbers>`. But essentially, what we're looking for are the lines that have `/home` in them.
8. Put a `#` in front of the second line of the two. So, it should look like this:

   ```
   # /home was on /dev/sda4 during installation
   #UUID=<random-numbers> /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
   ```

   Putting that `#` basically means that 'this line is a comment', so we're essentially deleting it, but we're not going to actually delete it.
9. Save and close the editor. This will take you back to the terminal.
10. `ls /home`. You should **not** see any output. If you don't see any output, continue on with the steps. If you see your username as the output (highly unlikely), go to step 13.

    - This command is basically checking if you already have a home folder. You should not see any folders there because all of your `/home` directory was mounted on a separate partition anyways.
11. `sudo mkdir /home/userName`. Don't forget, replace `userName` with your Ubuntu username.

    - This is creating a new home directory for your username. But it has incorrect ownership, so we'll fix it in a while.
12. `sudo cp /etc/skel/{e*,.[a-z]*} /home/userName`

    - This will copy some essential files to your new home folder.
13. `sudo chown -R userName:userName /home/userName`

    - This is changing the ownership of your new home folder to be you.

    > **Note**: There might be an easier, one command method to accomplish steps 11, 12 and 13, but meh, I don't know of it.
14. `exit`
15. `exit`

This should close the terminal.

At this point, we have removed auto-mounting your `/home` partition, created a new home folder for your username, copied some essential files to it, and gave it the correct permissions.

Shutdown this live Ubuntu. Remove the USB stick. Boot into your Ubuntu as you normally would. Cross your fingers. You **should** boot normally, and find that you have a home folder with all the subdirectories (Documents, Pictures, etc.) just like you did, but now, all of this is under one partition, the root partition.

Let's do some checks.

1. `cat /etc/fstab`. Look for the `#` that we added to that line. It should be there.
2. `ls -l /home`. You should see something like this:

   ```
   drwxr-xr-x 43 userName userName  4096 Jun 30 20:49 userName
   ```

   As long as those bold words are your username, everything is good.
3. `ls -l /home/userName`. You should see all of those subdirectories created, and all of them should have your username in place of those bold words above as well.
4. Open GParted. You should not see `/home` as the mount point for that partition (`/dev/sda4`) like in your screenshot.

If all of this checks out, congratulations!

At this point, your other partition (the one that used to be `/home`) is now free for you to do whatever you want with. Open GParted, and delete it, format it, burn it, throw it out the airlock, whatever.

<sub>Phew.</sub>

Comment: Wow, thanks for writing all that out. Bad news ... I needed to run Windows repair and it ate my GRUB. I'm going to try booting from my Ubuntu install DVD and try replacing it. I'll have come back to this later. I appreciate all the help so far!

Comment: Sorry, I had some unrelated technical issues, and I finally got around to trying this out. I got stuck on step #4. It tells me "chroot: missing operand".

Comment: oops ... disregard that last comment ... forgot the space+period at the end. Problem on step #5 though: "joe is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported". Should I expect the authorities at my door shortly? ;)

Comment: Ha, no, we'll hide from them. Before step 4, do `sudo chroot .`, then `adduser joe sudo`, then `exit`, then continue with the steps, starting from 4.

Comment: no luck ...
`ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/rt$ sudo chroot .`
`root@ubuntu:/# adduser joe sudo`
`The user 'joe' is already a member of 'sudo'.`
`root@ubuntu:/# exit`
`exit`
`ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/rt$ sudo chroot --userspec=joe:joe .`
`joe@ubuntu:/$ sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak`
`sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu` 
 `[sudo] password for joe: ` 
 `joe is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will bereported.`

Comment: That's weird. Okay, just replace step 4 with `sudo chroot .`, and continue with the steps. You can omit the word `sudo` from all the following commands.

Comment: Step 6 ... `root@ubuntu:/# gedit /etc/fstab`
`No protocol specified`
`** (gedit:5527): WARNING **: Could not open X display`
`No protocol specified`
`Cannot open display: `
`Run 'gedit --help' to see a full list of available command line options.`

Comment: Step 6: `nano /etc/fstab`. This will open the file in an editor within the terminal. Navigate using the arrow keys. When you're done adding the `#` (step 8), do Ctrl+X, then Y, then Enter to save and close the file.

Comment: All done! My home directory had a number "15" before it, instead of "43" in your example, but everything is just how I wanted. Thank you very much for your patience and walking me through this, Alaa. It would have taken ages to figure out how to do that myself. I still have much to learn. All the best to you.

Comment: The number '15' is not an issue if it's different. I would've been surprised if it were the same as mine =); you'll find the number growing as you create files and folders under your home folder anyways. And you're welcome, that's what this place is for.